# Horizontal overflow does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

Basically I have a column within a container to display times like a TV guide and by adding in each hour i.e. 13:00 to 14:00, the time goes onto the next line as opposed to allowing me to scroll horizontally, its hard to explain it basically displays 5 hours of times from 5am to 1pm and then goes to the next line as opposed to continuing on and allowing me to scroll horizontally I have to drag the mouse on the time like Im copying and pasting in order to see the times below.
Below is the CSS at the moment, I've tried every overflow option and it hasn't had any effect.
This is what I am trying to display

```
 <div id = "times">
        <div class = "header">05:00-06:00</div>
        <div class = "header">06:00-07:00</div>
        <div class = "header">07:00-08:00</div>
        <div class = "header">08:00-09:00</div>
        <div class = "header">09:00-10:00</div>
        <div class = "header">11:00-12:00</div>
        <div class = "header">12:00-13:00</div>
        <div class = "header">13:00-14:00</div>
        <div class = "header">14:00-15:00</div>
        <div class = "header">15:00-16:00</div>
        <div class = "header">16:00-17:00</div>
        <div class = "header">17:00-18:00</div>
        <div class = "header">18:00-19:00</div>
        <div class = "header">19:00-20:00</div>
        <div class = "header">20:00-21:00</div>
        <div class = "header">21:00-22:00</div>
        <div class = "header">22:00-23:00</div>
        <div class = "header">23:00-24:00</div>
```

This is the CSS

```css
#times{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you could share?

Comment: if `its hard to explain` then how do you suppose that `we will understand it` ? Please read `SO` guidelines before posting questions ..

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this shows?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/z7t42tdt/1/)

Comment: Yes jbutler but I cant get it to work

Comment: The snippet you just posted is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this question and ran with it. The snippet below should produce a TV guide with show times. It still needs to be heavily cleaned up, but it does what it needs to do.

I will come back to this when I have more time and clean it up some more.

I made this as dynamic as possible. All you have to do is provide a location to stick the table and provide it with data as the gird will be built from the provided data.

```js
/*
 * Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
 * MIT license
 *
 * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
 * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
 *
 * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
 * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
 * The date defaults to the current date/time.
 * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
 */

var dateFormat = function () {
    var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
        timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
        timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
        pad = function (val, len) {
            val = String(val);
            len = len || 2;
            while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
            return val;
        };

    // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
    return function (date, mask, utc) {
        var dF = dateFormat;

        // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
        if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
            mask = date;
            date = undefined;
        }

        // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
        date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
        if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

        mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

        // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
        if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
            mask = mask.slice(4);
            utc = true;
        }

        var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
            d = date[_ + "Date"](),
            D = date[_ + "Day"](),
            m = date[_ + "Month"](),
            y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
            H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
            M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
            s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
            L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
            o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
            flags = {
                d:    d,
                dd:   pad(d),
                ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                m:    m + 1,
                mm:   pad(m + 1),
                mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                yyyy: y,
                h:    H % 12 || 12,
                hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                H:    H,
                HH:   pad(H),
                M:    M,
                MM:   pad(M),
                s:    s,
                ss:   pad(s),
                l:    pad(L, 3),
                L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
            };

        return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
            return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
        });
    };
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
    "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
    shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
    mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
    longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
    fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
    shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
    mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
    longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
    isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
    isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
    isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
    isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
    dayNames: [
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ],
    monthNames: [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};

var utcDate = function (year, month, day, hour, min, sec) {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, min, sec));
};

var frmt = function(date) {
    return date.format('shortTime');
};

var data = [{
    name: 'CNN',
    shows: [{
        title: 'News',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 15, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0)
    }, {
        title: 'More News',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 18, 0, 0)
    }]
}, {
    name: 'ESPN',
    shows: [{
        title: 'Sports',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 15, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0)
    }, {
        title: 'More Sports',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 17, 0, 0)
    }]
}, {
    name: 'TBS',
    shows: [{
        title: 'Comedy',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 15, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 15, 30, 0)
    }, {
        title: 'More Comedy',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 15, 30, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0)
    }, {
        title: 'Even More Comedy',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 0, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 30, 0)
    }, {
        title: 'Too Much Comedy',
        startDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 16, 30, 0),
        endDate: utcDate(2014, 11, 17, 17, 30, 0)
    }]
}]

$(document).ready(function () {
    var guide = $('#guide');

    var generateMetadata = function (guide, data) {
        var calcStartDate = function (date, showDate) {
            return date === undefined || date.getTime() > showDate.getTime() ? showDate : date;
        };

        var calcEndDate = function (date, showDate) {
            return date === undefined || date.getTime() < showDate.getTime() ? showDate : date;
        };
        
        // Needs work...
        var calcMinStep = function (step, show) {
            var start = show.startDate.getMinutes();
            var end = show.endDate.getMinutes();
            var min = start < end ? start : end;
            return step === undefined || step > min && min !== 0 ? min : step;
        };

        var startDate = undefined;
        var endDate = undefined;
        var minStep = 60;
        var channelCount = 0;
        
        $.each(data, function (cIdx, channel) {
            $.each(channel.shows, function (sIdx, show) {
                startDate = calcStartDate(startDate, show.startDate);
                endDate = calcEndDate(endDate, show.endDate);
                minStep = calcMinStep(minStep, show); // Needs work...
            });
            channelCount++;
        });
        return {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
            step: minStep * 60000,
            channelCount : channelCount
        };
    };
    
    var generateBlocks = function(metaData) {
        var blocks = [];
        var currDate = new Date();
        currDate.setTime(metaData.startDate.getTime());
        while (currDate.getTime() < metaData.endDate.getTime()) {
            var currBlock = {};
            currBlock.startDate = frmt(currDate);
            currDate.setTime(currDate.getTime() + metaData.step);
            currBlock.endDate = frmt(currDate);
            blocks.push(currBlock);
        }
        return blocks;
    };

    var calcDuration = function(show, step) {
        var start = show.startDate.getTime();
        var end = show.endDate.getTime();
        return (end - start) / step;
    };
    
    var createTable = function (guide, data) {
        var metaData = generateMetadata(guide, data);
        var blocks = generateBlocks(metaData);
        
        console.log(blocks);
        
        var table = $('<table>');
        var thead = $('<thead>').appendTo(table);
        var theadr = $('<tr>').appendTo(thead);
        var tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo(table);
        
        theadr.append($('<td>').html(''));
        for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            theadr.append($('<td>').html(blocks[i].startDate));
        }
        
        $.each(data, function (cIdx, channel) {
            var tbodyr = $('<tr>').appendTo(tbody);
            console.log(channel.name);
            tbodyr.append($('<td>').html(channel.name));
            $.each(channel.shows, function (sIdx, show) {
                var duration = calcDuration(show, metaData.step);
                tbodyr.append($('<td>').attr('colspan', duration).html(show.title));
            });
        });
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(metaData, undefined, '    '));
        
        guide.append(table);
    };

    createTable(guide, data);
});
```

```css
.scroll {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td, th, table {
    border:  solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

thead {
    border-bottom: double 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll" id="guide"></div>
```